# how to perform a somewhat complicated ActiveRecord scope query for a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So, I have a `Notification` model that is polymorphic, and I want to be able to filter out notifications that are of a `notifiable_type` `Comment` where `comment.user == current_user`.  In other words, I want all notification records--except for ones referring to comments that were made by the current user.

```
class Notification

  belongs_to :notifiable, :polymorphic => true

  scope :relevant, lambda { |user_id|
    find(:all, :conditions => [
      "notifiable_type != 'Comment' OR (notifiable_type = 'Comment' AND " <<
        "comments.user_id != ?)",
      user_id ],
      :include => :comments
    )
  }

end
```

What I don't understand is what I need to do to get access to comments?  I need to tell ActiveRecord to outer join the comment model on `notifiable_id`.

Comment: What result are you getting from the above? E.g. What do you get if you call `Notification.relevant.first.comments`?

Comment: an error..  "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'comments' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"..  Because Notification doesn't have comments.. it has a "notifiable" which can be a comment, or some other model instance.

Comment: but you're saying to `:include => :comments` shouldn't you say `:include => :notifiables` or something like that?  Is a Comment a Notifiable?

Comment: with :include => :notifiable, I get:  "ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :notifiable"..  Hence my problem and my question..

Answer (score 4):

First, lambda scopes with parameters are deprecated. Use a class method instead:

```
class Notification
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

  def self.relevant(user_id)
    # ...
  end
end
```

I usually move scope functions into their own module, but you can leave it there.

Next, `find(:all)` is deprecated, as is `:conditions`. We use [ActiveRelation queries](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface) now.

Unfortunately, the `ActiveRecord::Relation` API isn't quite robust enough to do what you need, so we'll have to drop down to ARel instead. A little bit tricky, but you definitely don't want to be doing string substitution for security reasons.

```
class Notification
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

  def self.relevant(user_id)
    n, c = arel_table, Comment.arel_table
    predicate = n.join(c).on(n[:notifiable_id].eq(c[:id]))

    joins( predicate.join_sql ).
    where{ ( notifiable_type != 'Comment' ) | 
      (( notifiable_type == 'Comment' ) & ( comments.user_id == my{user_id} ))
    }
  end
end
```

I'm using a combination of ARel and [Squeel](http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/) here. Squeel is so good it should be a Rails core feature. I tried writing that where clause without Squeel, but it was so difficult I gave up.

Hard to test something like this without your project handy, but hopefully that should at least get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, your code has `:include => :comments`, plural, which threw me off. How about this?

```
class Notification
  belongs_to :notifiable, :polymorphic => true

  scope :relevant, lambda { |user_id|
    find(:all, :conditions => [
      "notifiable_type != 'Comment' OR (notifiable_type = 'Comment' AND " <<
        "comments.user_id != ?)",
      user_id ],
      :include => :notifiable
    )
  }

end
```

...then `Notification.relevant.first.notifiable` should work. From the docs:

> Eager loading is supported with polymorphic associations.
>
> > ```
> > class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
> >   belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
> > end
> > ```
>
> A call that tries to eager load the addressable model
>
> > ```
> > Address.find(:all, :include => :addressable)
> > ```
>
> This will execute one query to load the addresses and load the
>   addressables with one query per addressable type. For example if all
>   the addressables are either of class Person or Company then a total of
>   3 queries will be executed. The list of addressable types to load is
>   determined on the back of the addresses loaded. **This is not supported
>   if Active Record has to fallback to the previous implementation of
>   eager loading and will raise**
>   `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError`**. The reason is that the
>   parent model’s type is a column value so its corresponding table name
>   cannot be put in the FROM/JOIN clauses of that query.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: I just tried it...  Notification.relevant(123) gives me: "ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :notifiable"...  Yet, Notification.find(:all, :include => :notifiable) works ok.

Comment: Did some more experimenting, the error comes specifically when trying to address "comments.xxx" in the conditions.  When I take that part out, it works fine.  I need a way to tell ActiveRecord that notifiable is the table comments (and to join that)...

Comment: @patrick Yeah, working on it. Arel predicates make my brain hurt. This is a case where installing a gem is almost mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've resorted to.....  I am still hoping someone can show me a better way.

```
Notification.find_by_sql( "SELECT * from Notifications " <<
  "INNER JOIN comments ON notifiable_id = comments.id " <<
  "WHERE notifiable_type != 'Comment' " <<
    "OR (notifiable_type = 'Comment' AND comments.user_id = '#{user_id}')"
)
```

Comment: I'm also having this kind of problem right now but I asked it in a different way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596440/notifications-ala-facebook-database-implementation.

But same problem with you, what would you do if there is like, a lot of tables already (the notifiables)? Would you do an n join with the query?