# Notifications ala Facebook (database implementation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, facebook, database-design, notifications

I am wondering how Facebook implements their notifications system as I'm looking to do something similar.

- FooBar commented on your status
- Red1, Green2 and Blue3  commented on your photo
- MegaMan and 5 others commented on your event

I can't have multiple notifications written into a single record, as eventually I will have actions associated with each notification. Also, in the view I'd like notifications to be rendered as expandable lists when a certain number of them exist for a single subject.

- FooBar commented on your status (actions)
- Red1, Green2 and Pink5  commented on your photo [+]
- MegaMan and 3 others commented on your event [-]

  - MegaMan commented on your event (actions)
  - ProtoMan commented on your event (actions)
  - Bass commented on your event (actions)
  - DrWilly commented on your event (actions)

Cheers!

**PS** I am using postgres and rails BTW.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to go about implementing this. It really depends on what kinds of notifications you want to cover and what information you need to collect about the notification to show it to the right user(s). If you are looking for a simple design that just covers notifications about posted comments, you could use a combination of [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) and [observer callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers):

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
# or Status or Event
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commenter
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true # the photo, status or event
end

class CommentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :comment
    belongs_to :target_user
end

class CommentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :comment

    def after_create(comment)
        ...
        CommentNotification.create!(comment_id: comment.id,
          target_user_id: comment.commentable.owner.id)
        ...
    end
end
```

What's happening here is that each photo, status, event etc. has many comments. A `Comment` obviously belongs to a `:commenter` but also to a `:commentable`, which is either a photo, status, event or any other model that you want to allow comments for. You then have a `CommentObserver` that will observe your `Comment` model and do something whenever something happens with the `Comment` table. In this case, after a `Comment` is created, the observer will create a `CommentNotification` with the id of the comment and the id of the user who owns the thing that the comment is about (`comment.commentable.owner.id`). This would require that you implement a simple method `:owner` for each model you want to have comments for. So, for example, if the commentable is a photo, the owner would be the user who posted the photo.

This basic design should be enough to get you started, but note that if you want to create notifications for things other than comments, you could extend this design by using a polymorphic association in a more general `Notification` model.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :notifiable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :target_user
end
```

With this design, you would then 'observe' all your `notifiables` (models that you want to create notifications for) and do something like the following in your `after_create` callback:

```
class GenericObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :comment, :like, :wall_post

    def after_create(notifiable)
        ...
        Notification.create!(notifiable_id: notifiable.id, 
                           notifiable_type: notifiable.class.name,
                            target_user_id: notifiable.user_to_notify.id)
        ...
    end
end
```

The only tricky part here is the `user_to_notify` method. All models that are `notifiable` would have to implement it in some way depending on what the model is. For example, `wall_post.user_to_notify` would just be the owner of the wall, or `like.user_to_notify` would be the owner of the thing that was 'liked'. You might even have multiple people to notify, like when notifying all the people tagged in a photo when someone comments on it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is going to save me many headaches so I'm adding a bounty as a token of appreciation, but I can't assign it until after 24h.

Comment: @Duopixel Much appreciated! Let me know if you need expansion on anything.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to come up to this as well, but without the observer part. I just have it in like an after_create for now. But how can I display something like the examples I have given. Like, the first few names of the users that posted, say a comment?

Comment: @index First, what kinds of "actions" do you want to display next to your notifications? Do you mean like "delete", "respond", etc.?

Comment: Yes. Delete and Reply (but goes to personal messages so I don't need to tie in the comments to the notifications) and some others.

Comment: @Duopixel. I've posted a new answer that answers my stuff by the display but I don't know how it would scale and stuff or how it would compare to FB's notifications. I'd really appreciate a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to post this as another answer because the first was getting ridiculously long.

To render the comment notifications as expandable lists as you note in your
examples, you first collect the comments that have notifications for some target user (don't forget to add `has_one :notification` to the `Comment` model).

```
comments = Comment.joins(:notification).where(:notifications => { :target_user_id => current_user.id })
```

Note that the use of `joins` here generates an `INNER JOIN`, so you correctly exclude any comments that don't have notifications (as some notifications might have been deleted by the user).

Next, you want to group these comments by their commentables so that you can create an expandable list for each commentable.

```
@comment_groups = comments.group_by { |c| "#{c.commentable_type}#{c.commentable_id}"}
```

which will generate a hash like

```
`{ 'Photo8' => [comment1, comment2, ...], 'Event3' => [comment1, ...], ... }`
```

that you can now use in your view.

In `some_page_showing_comment_notifications.html.erb`

```
...
<ul>
  <% @comment_groups.each do |group, comments| %>
    <li>
      <%= render 'comment_group', :comments => comments, :group => group %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
...
```

In `_comment_group.html.erb`

```
<div>
  <% case comments.length %>
    <% when 1 %>
      <%= comments[0].commenter.name %> commented on your <%= comment[0].commentable_type.downcase %>.
    <% when 2 %>
      <%= comments[0].commenter.name %> and <%= comments[1].commenter.name %> commented on your <%= comment[0].commentable_type.downcase %>.
    <% when 3 %>
      <%= comments[0].commenter.name %>, <%= comments[1].commenter.name %> and <%= comments[2].commenter.name %> commented on your <%= comment[0].commentable_type.downcase %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'long_list_comments', :comments => comments, :group => group %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In `_long_list_comments.html.erb`

```
<div>
  <%= comments[0].commenter.name %> and <%= comments.length-1 %> others commented on your <%= comments[0].commentable_type %>.
  <%= button_tag "+", class: "expand-comments-button", id: "#{group}-button" %>
</div>
<%= content_tag :ul, class: "expand-comments-list", id: "#{group}-list" do %>
  <li>
    <% comments.each do |comment| %>
      # render each comment in the same way as before
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Finally, it should be a simple matter to add some javascript to `button.expand-comments-button` to toggle the `display` property of `ul.expand-comments-list`. Each button and list has a unique id based on the comment group keys, so you can make each button expand the correct list.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry for the late reply. This would start from the object itself (Comment) but I don't think I have mentioned but there are other's that need notifications as well. I have actually made a little something before, can you check and see if it's okay (posted as a new answer)?

Answer (score 0):

So I have kinda made a little something before the second answer was posted but got a bit too busy to compose and put it here. And I'm still studying if I did the right thing here, if it would scale or how it would perform overall. I would like to hear all your ideas, suggestions, comments to the way I have implemented this. Here goes:

So I first created the tables as typical polymorphic tables.

```
# migration
create_table :activities do |t|
  t.references :receiver
  t.references :user
  t.references :notifiable
  t.string :notifiable_type  # 
  t.string :type             # Type of notification like 'comment' or 'another type'
  ...
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications, :foreign_key => :receiver_id, :dependent => :destroy
end

# notification.rb
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :notifiable, :polymorphic => true

  COMMENT = 'Comment'
  ANOTHER_TYPE = 'Another Type'
end
```

So it's just this. Then inserts quite typically like when a user does a certain type of notification. So what's new that I found for psql is [ARRAY_AGG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) which is an aggregate function that groups a certain field into a new field as an array (but string when it gets to rails). So how I'm getting the records are now like this:

```
# notification.rb

scope :aggregated,
  select('type, notifiable_id, notifiable_type,
    DATE(notifications.created_at),
    COUNT(notifications.id) AS count,
    ARRAY_AGG(users.name) AS user_names,
    ARRAY_AGG(users.image) as user_images,
    ARRAY_AGG(id) as ids').
  group('type, notifiable_id, notifiable_type, DATE(notifications.created_at)').
  order('DATE(notifications.created_at) DESC').
  joins(:user)
```

This outputs something like:

```
type     | notifiable_id | notifiable_type | date | count | user_names                     | user_images                  | id
"Comment"| 3             | "Status"        |[date]| 3     | "['first', 'second', 'third']" |"['path1', 'path2', 'path3']" |"[1, 2, 3]"
```

And then in my notifications model again, I have this methods which basically just puts them back to an array and removes the non-uniques (so that a name won't be displayed twice in a certain aggregated notification):

```
# notification.rb

def array_of_aggregated_users
  self.user_names[1..-2].split(',').uniq
end

def array_of_aggregated_user_images
  self.user_images[1..-2].split(',').uniq
end
```

Then in my view I have something like this

```
# index.html.erb
<% @aggregated_notifications.each do |agg_notif| %>
  <% 
    all_names = agg_notif.array_of_aggregated_users
    all_images = agg_notif.array_of_aggregated_user_images
  %>

  <img src="<%= all_images[0] %>" />

  <% if all_names.length == 1 %>
    <%= all_names[0] %>
  <% elsif all_names.length == 2 %>
    <%= all_names[0] %> and <%= all_names[1] %>
  <% elsif all_names.length == 3 %>
    <%= all_names[0] %>, <%= all_names[1] %> and <%= all_names[2] %>
  <% else %>
    <%= all_names[0] %> and <%= all_names.length - 1 %> others
  <% end %>

  <%= agg_notif.type %> on your <%= agg_notif.notifiable_type %>

  <% if agg_notif.count > 1 %>
    <%= set_collapsible_link # [-/+] %>
  <% else %>
    <%= set_actions(ids[0]) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```